# Rails 3: Rails console not opening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3

Suddenly, I'm not able to open the console or anything else related to the ActiveRecord in my app.

I always get this error:

```
~/Code/act(master) $ rails c
/Users/donald/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:295:in `table_structure': Could not find table 'wsps' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
 from /Users/donald/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:186:in `columns'
 from /Users/donald/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:679:in `columns'
 from /Users/donald/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:692:in `column_names'
 from /Users/donald/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/validates_lengths_from_database-0.1.2/lib/validates_lengths_from_database.rb:20:in `validates_lengths_from_database'
```

I've tried this solution https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/99-sqlite-connection-failing with no effect.

What am I doing wrong here? Even when I checkout version who used to work from github I get the same error.

Regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
rake db:migrate
```

I am assuming either you started in a new folder, or you added a new migration. The error states clearly that the table `wsps` cannot be found.

Comment: No. that was not the problem. I couldn't even run rake db:migrate. If I ignored the table wsps, the table users would give error, etc. I fixed it just by removing all the gems in the gemfile and adding one by one.. don't ask me why but it worked.

Comment: Ok, great you were able to solve it yourself. An easy way to remove all gems and re-install would be using a different gemset (i see you are using rvm). Good thing to remember: if something akward goes wrong, try again in a new, bare gemset. But it is weird why that should help in this case :)